# Passing variables through URL in Jqgrid to controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

How do I pass values from url to Jqgrid, the issue is the Jqgrid needs to be loaded based on edit link on previous page, and we have the URL like:

```
    http://localhost:49771/Search/EditSearchResults?id=ID_HelpTopics&action=edit
```

I need to be able to use this id in URL for populating the grid data, so I need to pass this value through grid to controller to get the results and the grid I have is like:

```
            $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("EditSearchResults", new {controller = "JSonData" }) %>', 
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['Language', 'ID'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Language', index: 'Language', editable: false, width: 40, align: 'left', sortable: false },
               { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 40, editable: true, edittype: "text", align: 'left', editoptions: { size: 5, maxlength: 30 }, sortable: false }, ],

            editurl: '<%= Url.Action("EditSearchResults", new {controller = "JSONData"}) %>',
            pager: '#pager',
            //autowidth: true,
            width: "500",
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 20,
            height: "200",
            loadonce: false,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            recordtext: "View Records {0} - {1} of {2}",
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
            sortname: 'Results',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            scroll: false,
            loadonce: false,
            caption: 'Edit Search Results',
            ondblClickRow: function (id) {
                if (id != null) {
                        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', id);
                        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true, false, processEdit);
                        lastsel = id;
                }

            }
        });
        });
```

How can use the current URL to pass id to controller to populate jqgrid, How should the controller and jqgrid should be like? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url.Action will take a anonymous object as a parameter set

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("EditSearchResults", 
                     new {controller = "JSonData" },
                     new {id = Request.Params[id] }) %>',
```

However it would be preferable to make that part of your model than depending on the Request.

Comment: That work perfect, we need to have id as string Request.Params["id"]. How can we make it a part of model though?

Comment: 1) add the field to your model
2) Assign the field in your controller - model.requestId = Request.Params[id];

Comment: I am using cakePHP and my url is like this `<?php echo OWNER_BASE_PATH."users/viewzones";  ?>` . so how can i pass a variable to Controller?